# r data.table: Subsetting and assignment by reference in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

Seems like an easy one, but... well...

Given a named vector of regular expressions and a data table as follows:

```
library(data.table)
regexes <- c(a="^A$") 
dt <- fread("
a,A,1
a,B,1
b,A,1
")
```

The **input** data table is

```
dt
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1:  a  A  1
# 2:  a  B  1
# 3:  b  A  1
```

My goal for the 1st element in `regexes` would be:

If `V1=="a"` set `V3:=2`. EXCEPT when `V2` matches the corresponding regular expression `^A$`, then `V3:=3`.

(`a` is `names(regexes)[1]`, `^A$` is `regexes[1]`, `2` and `3` are just for demo purpose. I also got more names and regular expressions to loop over, and the data set is about 300.000 rows.)

So the  **expected output** is

```
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1:  a  A  3 (*)
# 2:  a  B  2 (**)
# 3:  b  A  1
```

(*) `3` because `V1` is `a` and `V2` (`A`) matches the regex,
(**) `2` because `V1` is `a` and `V2` (`B`) does not match `^A$`.

**I tried** to loop through the regexes and pipe the subsetting through like this:

```
for (x in seq(regexes)) 
  dt[V1==names(regexes)[x], V3:=2][grepl(regexes[x], V2), V3:=3]
```

However...

```
dt
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1:  a  A  3 
# 2:  a  B  2
# 3:  b  A  3 <- wrong, should remain 2
```

... it does not work as expected, `grepl` uses the complete `V2`column, not just the `V1=="a"` subset. I also tried some other things, which worked, but took too long (i.e. not the way to use data.table).

**Question**: What would be the best data table way to go here? I'm using `packageVersion("data.table")` `‘1.9.7’`.

---

Note that I could go the data frame route e.g. like this

```
df <- as.data.frame(dt)
for (x in seq(regexes)) {
  idx <- df$V1==names(regexes)[x]
  df$V3[idx] <- 2
  df$V3[idx][grepl(regexes[x], df$V2[idx])] <- 3 # or ifelse()
}
```

But - of course - I would not want to convert the data.table to a data.frame and then back to a data.table if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dt[condition, blah := boo]` returns the modified *full* `dt` (smth you can check by adding extra empty `[]` at the end) - thus the result you get. Add the extra condition to the 2nd set of `[]`.

Comment: I tried that, @eddi, however when I use `V1==names(regexes)[x] & grepl(regexes[x], V2)` as a condition (i.e. match each regex over all `V2`s), it takes ~35 seconds, whereas the data frame example takes ~3. So I thought that is clearly not the way to go here.

Comment: Something seems fishy about that. Can you add a larger example where the slowdown can be seen?

Comment: To me it sounds reasonable. Although data.table might automatically build an index for `V1`, `grepl` still runs several times over 300.000 rows, not over a few subsets of maybe 200 to 2000 rows, like in the data frame example. Still think a bigger example would be beneficial here? In that case I could try and build an artificial one.

Comment: ok, gotcha, you're right, no need for an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... it does not work as expected, `grepl` uses the complete `V2` column, not just the `V1=="a"` subset.

I would use stringi, which allows for easy vectorization of regex tests:

```
library(stringi)
dt[V1 %in% names(regexes), 
  V3 := V3 + 1L + stri_detect(V2, regex = regexes[V1])
]

   V1 V2 V3
1:  a  A  3
2:  a  B  2
3:  b  A  1
```

The `stri_detect` family of functions are like `grepl` from base.

Comment: Thanks Frank, didn't know about `stri_detect`, yet. However, `names(regexes)` and `regexes` are tied together in my real data, and `regexes` is in fact not numeric (I feared the example could be misleading, but.. well..). I still think the best way to conquer it would be to (1.) subset each `names(regex)`, (2.) set a default value and then (3.) set a new value for the matches. Let me know if I should work out a better example...

Comment: @lukeA I don't follow. This way does not assume that regexes are numeric (whatever that might mean)... If there's something to do with the size of your example that makes this way slow, though, yeah, a better example (as a function of `n`) would be good.

Comment: I mean `V3`, the target column, is not numeric. I thought I (1) set it to a default value for the subsets (= `names(regexes)`), and then (2) to a flag value for the regex matches in that subset. Key here is, that each subset has its own regex. So you can't vectorize over the regexes.

Comment: @lukeA You can totally vectorize over regexes. If your `regexes` object contained `b` in addition to `a`, stringi would work just fine, and much more efficiently than if grouping. If you need string values for V3 ("3", "2", "1") instead of numeric, that's a simple change. You can change your fread call to make your example have V3 string and I'll update the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, and I think got your point, however, to my knowledge vectorization would only work if _all_ regexes would apply to _all_ subsets. In my case, each value of the regexes vector should _only_ be checked within the subset given by its name. You see what I mean?

Comment: @lukeA It's like when you do `mapply(grepl, regexes[V1], V2)`. The arguments are matched up. In `regexes[V1]`, you have the same regex showing up every time V1=="a". Try `y = c(1,2,3,1,1,1); x = 1:3; x[y]`. The latter has the length of `y`... not sure if that's where the confusion lies.

Comment: You are right.. seems as if at some point one doesn't see the wood for the trees. I spent the last hour on trying to debug why most of the resulting values of `stri_detect` or `Vectorize` are `NA` (ICU flavor seems ok, no empty regexes, ...), but anyway... tomorrow is another day. Thanks for your help.